# Tilted grid network plotting in Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Here is an example figure as illustration.

[image]

This plot present the satellite SO2 column data for part of Europe.

Due to the difference between satellite and longitude, the grid network which fit the satellite scanning principle are not parallel to longitude.

I don't know if it's possible to draw this kind of grid network using pcolor or pcolormesh in matplotlib.basemap. So, I post my question here.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this question because I was also looking for a way to plot gridded satellite measurements on a map, using `matplotlib` and `basemap`.
I am not sure if my idea is relevant to your question, as my pixels can assume only a very limited discrete number of values (4), but I decided to answer anyway, also to find out if you eventually found an efficient solution. What I did was to directly plot *each* single pixel as a polygon on the map, by using the method `Polygon`.
I set the `alpha` value to be function of the underlying physical measurement. In my case—a cloud mask plot—this strategy works out pretty well.
Here's the function that gets called for each pixel to be plotted:

```
def draw_cloud_pixel(lats, lons, index, mapplot):
    """Draw a pixel on the map. The fill color alpha level depends on the cloud index, 
    ranging from 0.1 (almost fully transparent) for confidently clear pixels to 1 (fully opaque)
    for confidently cloudy pixels.

    Keyword arguments:
    lats -- Array of latitude values for the pixel 4 corner points (numpy array)
    lons -- Array of longitudes values for the pixel 4 corner points (numpy array)
    index -- Cloud mask index for given pixel: 
        0: confidently_cloudy
        1: probably_cloudy
        2: probably_clear
        3: confidently_clear
    mapplot -- Map object for coordinate transformation

    Returns:
    None
    """
    x, y = mapplot(lons, lats)
    xy = zip(x,y)
    poly = Polygon(xy, facecolor='white', alpha=1-0.3*index)
    plt.gca().add_patch(poly)
```

In my main plotting routine, I then call the `draw_cloud_pixel` function for each pixel in the selected region:

```
# draw plot, each pixel at the time
for scanline in xrange(select_cp_lat.shape[0]):
    for pixel in xrange(select_cp_lat.shape[1]):
        draw_cloud_pixel(select_cp_lat[scanline, pixel,:], 
                         select_cp_lon[scanline, pixel,:], 
                         cloud_mask[scanline, pixel], 
                         mapplot)
```

I get plots like this one:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look on different examples from this page: http://www.uvm.edu/~jbagrow/dsv/heatmap_basemap.html

Main idea of a sample is plot a `pcolormesh` on a `basemap`:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# load earthquake epicenters:
# http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_week.csv
lats, lons = [], []
with open('earthquake_data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader) # Ignore the header row.
    for row in reader:
        lat = float(row[1])
        lon = float(row[2])
        # filter lat,lons to (approximate) map view:
        if -130 <= lon <= -100 and 25 <= lat <= 55:
            lats.append( lat )
            lons.append( lon )

# Use orthographic projection centered on California with corners
# defined by number of meters from center position:
m  = Basemap(projection='ortho',lon_0=-119,lat_0=37,resolution='l',\
             llcrnrx=-1000*1000,llcrnry=-1000*1000,
             urcrnrx=+1150*1000,urcrnry=+1700*1000)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()

# ######################################################################
# bin the epicenters (adapted from 
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507575/basemap-and-density-plots)

# compute appropriate bins to chop up the data:
db = 1 # bin padding
lon_bins = np.linspace(min(lons)-db, max(lons)+db, 10+1) # 10 bins
lat_bins = np.linspace(min(lats)-db, max(lats)+db, 13+1) # 13 bins

density, _, _ = np.histogram2d(lats, lons, [lat_bins, lon_bins])

# Turn the lon/lat of the bins into 2 dimensional arrays ready
# for conversion into projected coordinates
lon_bins_2d, lat_bins_2d = np.meshgrid(lon_bins, lat_bins)

# convert the bin mesh to map coordinates:
xs, ys = m(lon_bins_2d, lat_bins_2d) # will be plotted using pcolormesh
# ######################################################################

# define custom colormap, white -> nicered, #E6072A = RGB(0.9,0.03,0.16)
cdict = {'red':  ( (0.0,  1.0,  1.0),
                   (1.0,  0.9,  1.0) ),
         'green':( (0.0,  1.0,  1.0),
                   (1.0,  0.03, 0.0) ),
         'blue': ( (0.0,  1.0,  1.0),
                   (1.0,  0.16, 0.0) ) }
custom_map = LinearSegmentedColormap('custom_map', cdict)
plt.register_cmap(cmap=custom_map)

# add histogram squares and a corresponding colorbar to the map:
plt.pcolormesh(xs, ys, density, cmap="custom_map")

cbar = plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal', shrink=0.625, aspect=20, fraction=0.2,pad=0.02)
cbar.set_label('Number of earthquakes',size=18)
#plt.clim([0,100])

# translucent blue scatter plot of epicenters above histogram:    
x,y = m(lons, lats)
m.plot(x, y, 'o', markersize=5,zorder=6, markerfacecolor='#424FA4',markeredgecolor="none", alpha=0.33)


# http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.drawmapscale
m.drawmapscale(-119-6, 37-7.2, -119-6, 37-7.2, 500, barstyle='fancy', yoffset=20000)

# make image bigger:
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(15,15)

plt.show()
```

[image]